# SignalR and .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm basically trying to dynamically create a list element and update it across multiple clients. I'm using SignalR library of .NET. Following is my code.

```
$(function () {
// Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.  
var listSync = $.connection.myHub1;

console.log("List Sync ");
// Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages and toggle.
listSync.client.addNewItemToPage = function (name, url) {

    console.log("List Sync 3");
    var play_list = document.getElementById('playlist');
    var empty = document.getElementById('empty');
    if (empty != null) {
        empty.remove();
    }
    var pli = document.createElement("li");
    var ptag = document.createElement('a');
    var icon = document.createElement('i');
    icon.setAttribute('class', "fa fa-toggle-right");
    ptag.setAttribute('href', "#");
    ptag.setAttribute('class', "play_track");
    ptag.appendChild(icon);
    ptag.innerHTML += name;
    ptag.type = url;
    pli.appendChild(ptag);
    play_list.appendChild(pli);

    //handler to play songs by playlist
    var favLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('play_track');
    for (var j = 0; j < favLinks.length; j++) {
        var favLink = favLinks[j];
        favLink.onclick = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            xurl = this.type;
            myFunc();
        }
    }

};

// Start the connection.
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    window.listFunc = function listFunc(name, url) {

        console.log("List Sync 1");
        // Call the Send method on the hub. 
        listSync.server.update_playlist(name, url);

        console.log("List Sync 2");
    }
});

});
```

The problem is it doesn't go into the function listSync.client.addNewItemToPage. Can someone please tell me why?

Comment: Post the code where you call that client method from the server

Comment: I don't think it'll make any difference. See I'm using a simple button to call the function which passes arguments in listFunc(name, url). All this works fine but the listSync.client.addNewItemToPage() function doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't work, or is not getting called?

Comment: I think it's not getting called. I don't know why I already have a couple of functions and they are being called using the same method and even the same hub.

Comment: but you call Clients.All.addNewItemToPage from the server side?

Comment: Where's the hub location? Is it inside your current server?

Comment: Enable tracing on Hub:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing
Enable logging in client:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client
you should get something relevant (most probably on Hub)

Comment: Thanks but I solved my problem by removing arguments from listFunc function.